# Перестал работать android studio emulator - "Устройство, подключенное к системе, не работает"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Я запустил его в какой-то момент, и он был очень очень медленным, однако после того, как я закрыл его и открыл снова, он перестал работать с этой ошибкой:

> UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect не удалось для ptDst = (2713, 154), size = (697x21), dirty = ( 697x21 0, 0) (Устройство, подключенное к системе, не работает.)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте закрыть эмулятор, открыть AVD manager, сделать у эмулятора wipe data, после чего заходим в его настройки и у пункта Graphics выбираем Software - GLES 2.0.